# Python - how do i save a itertools.product loop and resume where it left off

Tags: python

I am writing a python script to basically check every possible url and log it if it responds to a request.

I found a post on StackOverflow that suggested a method of generating the strings for the urls which works well.

```
    for n in range(1, 4 + 1):
    for comb in product(chars, repeat=n):
        url = ("http://" + ''.join(comb) + ".com")
        currentUrl = url
        checkUrl(url)
```

As you can imagine there is way to many urls and it is going to take a very long time so I am trying to make a way to save my script and resume from were it left off.

My question is how can I have the loop start from a specific place, or does anyone have a working piece of code that does the same thing and will allow me to specify at starting point.

This is my script soo far..

```
import urllib.request
from string import digits, ascii_uppercase, ascii_lowercase
from itertools import product

goodUrls = "Valid_urls.txt"
saveFile = "save.txt"
currentUrl = ''


def checkUrl(url):
    print("Trying - "+url)
    try:
        urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    except Exception as e:
        None
    else:
        log = open(goodUrls, 'a')
        log.write(url + '\n')



chars = digits + ascii_lowercase

try:
    while True:
        for n in range(1, 4 + 1):
            for comb in product(chars, repeat=n):
                url = ("http://" + ''.join(comb) + ".com")
                currentUrl = url
                checkUrl(url)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Saving and Exiting")
    open(saveFile,'w').write(currentUrl)
```

Comment: Are you literally testing every possible character combination for whether there is a web site registered at that URI? Isn't there a smarter way to do that, asking some online registry or similar?

Comment: @tobias_k I think he will only check URLs consisting of 1-4 characters before a ".com" ending.  That's a mere 1.6 million URLs, an insignificant fraction of all the possibilities.  You must be right that scraping data from online registering agency sites is the only reasonable way to do this.

Comment: @tobias_k You can if you can prove legit use for it request access to listings of domain names (130million .com's at the moment for instance) - However, if one's first approach to getting some of those is to brute force combinations then... umm... it's unlikely there's sufficient proof there :)

Comment: If you can't find a useable online service for this, I'd suggest getting lists of words, names, places, brands, etc., and only testing those, and then combinations of 2, 3 and more of those. The number will still be massive and you will certainly miss a few URLs, but all in all you will probably find much more real URLs than with your appraoch.

Answer (score 3):

The return value of `itertools.product` is a generator object. As such all you'll have to do is:

```
products = product(...)

for foo in products:
    if bar(foo):
        spam(foo)
        break
# other stuff

for foo in products:
    # starts where you left off.
```

---

In your case the time taken to iterate through the possibilities is pretty small, at least compared to the time it'll take to make all those network requests. You could either save all the possibilities to disk and dump a list of what's left after every run of the program, or you could just save which *number* you're on. Since `product` has deterministic output, that should do it.

```
try:
    with open("progress.txt") as f:
        first_up = int(f.read().strip())
except FileNotFoundError:
    first_up = 0
try:
    for i, foo in enumerate(products):
        if i <= first_up:
            continue  # skip this iteration
        # do stuff down here
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # this is really rude to do, by the by....
    print("Saving and exiting"
    with open("progress.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(str(i))
```

If there's some reason you need a human-readable "progress" file, you can save your last password as you did above and do:

```
for foo in itertools.dropwhile(products, lambda p != saved_password):
    # do stuff
```

Comment: I think OP was talking about different executions of the program, i.e. writing the current state of the iterator to file or something like that.

Comment: @tobias_k Oh shoot, yes he was. Serializing it is a bit different. I'll edit.

Comment: Or, you treat the string as a base N number (where `N == len(chars)`) and convert to/from that number as needed. So for lowercase letters, 0 would be 'a' and 11881376 (`26 ** 5`) would be 'zzzzz'... Then you run through the numbers and converting them to strings for the check, when you stop, store the number such as 123456, then when you resume, you start counting from that instead of 0/bringing the generator up to date first. It also makes it easier to divide into blocks and multiprocess it etc...

Comment: @JonClements That's a pretty neat idea. Why don't you write that up as an answer? (Well, it neither really answers the question nor will it ultimately help OP with the URL finding problem, but it might still be of use to others.)

Comment: @tobias_k because I'm fairly sure I've made such an answer before on a question where it was directly relevant to the question... However, I'm starting to think I imagined it because I can't find it :)

Answer (score 3):

Although the attempt to find all the URLs by this method is ridiculous, the general question posed is a very good one.  The short answer is that you cannot pickle an iterator in a straightforward way, because the pickle mechanism can't save the iterator's internal state.  However, you *can* pickle an object that implements both `__iter__` and `__next__`.  So if you create a class that has the desired functionality and also works as an iterator (by implementing those two functions), it can be pickled and reloaded. The reloaded object, when you make an iterator from it, will continue from where it left off.

```
#! python3.6
import pickle

class AllStrings:
    CHARS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
    def __init__(self):
        self.indices = [0]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        s = ''.join([self.CHARS[n] for n in self.indices])
        for m in range(len(self.indices)):
            self.indices[m] += 1
            if self.indices[m] < len(self.CHARS):
                break
            self.indices[m] = 0
        else:
            self.indices.append(0)
        return s

try:
    with open("bookmark.txt", "rb") as f:
        all_strings = pickle.load(f)
except IOError:
    all_strings = AllStrings()

try:    
    for s in iter(all_strings):
        print(s)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    with open("bookmark.txt", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(all_strings, f)
```

This solution also removes the limitation on the length of the string.  The iterator will run forever, eventually generating all possible strings.  Of course at some point the application will stop due to the increasing entropy of the universe.

Comment: Haha Yes, I realize this sounds ridiculous and I'm sure it is, once I have this working I am going to tunnel over tor and use it to check onion links which I don't believe there is an accessible registrar for. there really is no reason to do this I just like to set my self crazy tasks to do when I start to learn a language.

Thanks for the input tho I will give that a try